# Compiling SDL Games on Mac

Tags: macos, sdl

I have a mac and I am trying to compile my projects. The standard on the wiki: g++ sdl.cpp -lSDLmain -lSDL -framework Cocoa does not seem to be working it returns that it cannot find -lSDL and -lSDLmain. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand the meaning of the flags? The linker is looking for the libraries SDL and SDLmain, are they setup on your machine?

Comment: They were and it was very different to what I was expecting, the solution is: gcc -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers MyProgram.c SDLmain.m -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution is as follows:

```
g++ -c -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers -I. -I.. -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Headers  -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_mixer.framework/Headers  -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Headers  -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_net.framework/Headers  -I/usr/local/include/SDL  -I/usr/local/include/ ./lesson20.cpp -o ./lesson20.o
```

Now that the object file has been created, we can use this solution:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers -I. -I.. -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_image.framework/Headers -lSDLmain  -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_mixer.framework/Headers  -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Headers  -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL_net.framework/Headers  -framework SDL -framework SDL_image -framework Cocoa  -framework SDL_mixer -framework SDL_ttf -framework SDL_net -framework OpenGL lesson20.o  -o Lesson
```

This solution assumes that you have the SDL_image, SDL_mixer, SDL_ttf, and SDL_net frameworks installed in the '/Library/Frameworks/' directory.

Since this is difficult to attempt by hand, and the solution is a little messy, it's better to simply write a script to do all of this for you.

The '-I' (capital i) flag tells the compiler where to look for headers.  The '-L' flag tells the compiler where to look for libraries.  The '-l' (lower case L) flag tells the compiler which libraries to use.  The '-framework' flag basically behaves like a '-l' (lower case L) flag.